# set median of a column to zero pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a a Dataframe with two columns and I want to set each of the columns median value to zero. How can i do this without changing the standard deviation ? Or better is this the right way to do that ?

suppose I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2))
#first column
df0=df[0]
#set median to zero
test=abs(df0-df.median())
```

Since I again looked for

```
test.median()
```

it is printing me not zero but a different value as above. Do I have a mistake in thought?

Comment: Think you should leave out `abs` and use  `df[0].median()` - now you are using the median of the table but substract on one column :)

Comment: You have a mistake. If you want the median to be 0 for each column. You should calculate, PER COLUMN the median. and subtract it from all rows in that column. taking abs will also ruin the new median = 0 you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want

```
test= df0 - df[0].median()

>>> test.median()
0.0
```

If you just get the absolute values of the series, you'll change the median value because of course, it depends on the ordering of elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 things you need to do here:

1. **Iterating over the columns**
2. **For each column, you want to calculate its median and substract it from all values (related to that column)**

And don't use absolute as it'll ruin the `median = 0` you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2))
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col] - np.median(df[col])
```

Testing:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(np.median(df[col]))

0.0
0.0
```